# Firebase-Admin save user's Custom userPropery

Tags: c#, firebase-admin

I'm trying to make a server side api call that will get a firebase token and make a

> setUserProperty

I managed to connect to firebaseAdmin and get the user , but I can't find how to update the user's custom field ,
I can only see user fields like email password etc...

This is what i got so far

```
 FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("firebase-adminsdk.json"),
        });


        // Then FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance will give you the initialized SDK Auth instance.
        // E.g.:
        var fbUser= await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.GetUserByPhoneNumberAsync("+91112324564");
        UserRecordArgs args = new UserRecordArgs();
```

Any ideas if it's at all possible ? (I don't want to do it from the app)